# ament_export_targets vs ament_export_interfaces

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In reference to this on ROS Discourse: https://discourse.ros.org/t/ament-best-practice-for-sharing-libraries/3602

What is the difference practically between these two lines and when should I use one over the other?

```
ament_export_targets(export_${PROJECT_NAME} HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)
```

and this one (as shown in the example at that link):

```
ament_export_interfaces(export_${PROJECT_NAME})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372164/ament_export_targets-vs-ament_export_interfaces/) by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2021-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replying to my own question.  I found in the official documentation (here: https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-CMake-Documentation/#building-a-library) this:

> The ament_export_targets macro (ament_export_interfaces in Eloquent and older) exports the targets for CMake.

This seems to imply that ament_export_targets is a rename of ament_export_interfaces and should now be used instead.

---

Originally posted by [tyler-picknik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48265/tyler-picknik/) with karma: 241 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2